# Redirect message from python console to txt file

Tags: python, batch-file, compiler-warnings

I'm using a Python script to call a batch file that call after the generation tools and compiler.  I save this to a output file using:

```
os.system("run.bat >output.txt")
```

The problem is that warnings and compiler error are not saved in this output file - they are only displayed on the Python console.

How would I go about saving the output to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do several things:

1. Use the `subprocess` family to get handles to the stdout and stderr files
2. Use a redirect of the stderr in your `os.system` call.

The first one is more pythonic, and allows your python script to be aware of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to redirect stderr to the same file is like this:

```
os.system("run.bat > output.txt 2>&1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use os.system ~ you have no error handling there, or even worse, you have no indicator if an error happened.

I would solve this problem like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(['run.bat'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

result = proc.communicate()

with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write(result[0])

with open('errors.txt', 'w') as errors:
    errors.write(result[-1])
```